# Where can I get an OpenStreetMap extract that includes Bike Lanes?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'd like some way to download an extract of OSM data, like [GeoFabrik](http://www.geofabrik.de/) or [BBBike](https://extract.bbbike.org/), that includes bike lanes. Does anyone have any advice or should I just try and figure them out with Osmosis?

Comment: There is a bit on the open street map wiki about exporting http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Export perhaps some of those tools will get you headed in the right direction. If there is a 'contact us' tab on their web page perhaps you can ask for a data extract for your purposes, they would probably be quite amiable if you ask nicely.

Comment: What do you mean? Extracts for regions like http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html *.osm.pbf or *.osm.bz2 have full sets of osm data, including bikelanes. If you asks about filtering these data to get bikelanes only, you could do it with OverpassAPI (online) or osmfilter (offline).

Comment: Hm, thanks Dmitry, I'll take a look at the *.osm.pbf and bz2 files that geofabrik offers- but bike lanes don't seem to be included in the .shp files? And Michael, I have downloaded raw OSM data before, but it can be ugly and I was hoping someone would do some standard parsing for me ;)

Comment: As far as I know the shapefiles from geofabrik don't include all information. You can either try to create your own shapefiles or import raw OSM data instead.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following steps:

1. Do you already know the tagging of OSM elements that represents bike lanes?
   Some documentation is in the OSM wiki about [cycleway](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:cycleway)
2. Do some queries via [overpass-turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) just to see for a special area how much tagging of bike lanes is inside the raw OSM database at all.
3. Via overpass-turbo you can also export the resulting data in different formats, read its documentation inside OSM wiki